# What public interface should I offer for creating objects that know about each other?

Tags: c#, object-oriented-design, api-design

I'm creating a library in C# which will be used to query databases.

In order to use this library, a user first needs to tell the library what the database schema contains, by creating `Schema`, `Table`, and `Column` objects.

A `Schema` object consists of:

- A name, which is a `string`.
- A collection of `Table` objects that it owns.

A `Table` object consists of:

- A reference to the `Schema` object that owns it.
- A name, which is a `string`.
- A collection of `Column` objects that it owns.

Finally, a `Column` object consists of:

- A reference to the `Table` object that owns it.
- A name, which is a `string`.
- A type, which is one of the values `String`, `DateTime`, and `Reference`.
- If the type is `Reference`, then a target, which is a reference to a `Table` object within the same `Schema`.

I can think of a ton of ways to design a public interface for creating these objects, but all of them have flaws. What approach should I use?

Here are the ideas I've thought of:

### Provide mutable classes only

The user can create `Schema`, `Table`, and `Column` objects, and then change all properties of these objects after the fact.

Downsides:

- Ensuring that the states of these objects remain consistent with each other could be difficult.
- Since all of these objects are mutable, the user will have to keep in mind that they could change at any time. (And so will I, the author of the library!)

### Provide immutable classes only: naive edition

The classes `Schema`, `Table`, and `Column` are all immutable. All properties of these objects must be specified when they are created. You can't create a `Schema` without specifying all of the `Table`s it contains, and you can't create a `Table` without specifying which `Schema` it belongs to.

Fatal downside:

- Creating objects wouldn't actually be possible: you can't create a schema without creating its tables first, and you can't create tables without creating the schema first.

### Provide immutable classes only: bottom-up construction

First, you create `Column` objects. Next, you create `Table` objects by passing in `Column` objects. Finally, you create a `Schema` object by passing in `Table` objects. All of these classes are immutable.

Downsides:

- The `Column` object can't have a property indicating which `Table` the column belongs to, because the `Column` object is created before the `Table` object is, and the `Column` object is immutable. Likewise, the `Table` object can't have a property indicating which `Schema` it belongs to.
- The "target table" property of a `Column` object will have to just be a string, not a reference to a `Table` object.
- The API user is forced to create objects in a specific order. What if you want to create tables first and add columns later?

### Provide two kinds of immutable classes

Provide two families of classes. First, there are the `SchemaDefinition`, `TableDefinition`, and `ColumnDefinition` classes, which work exactly as in the "bottom-up construction" approach.

There are also `Schema`, `Table`, and `Column` classes, which are also immutable. These classes have all the properties that you could hope for: a `Schema` has a property telling you about all of its `Table`s, and a `Table` has a property telling you which `Schema` it belongs to.

The `Schema`, `Table`, and `Column` classes have no public constructors. Instead, there's a `SchemaFactory` class which takes a `SchemaDefinition` and uses it to create a bunch of `Schema`, `Table`, and `Column` objects, and then gives you the `Schema`.

Downsides:

- There are two classes for each type of business object, instead of just one.
- The API user is *still* forced to create objects in a specific order.

### Provide mutable and immutable classes

Provide two families of classes. First, there are the `SchemaMutable`, `TableMutable`, and `ColumnMutable` classes, which work exactly as in the "provide mutable classes only" approach.

There are also `Schema`, `Table`, and `Column` classes, which work just like in the "two kinds of immutable classes" approach. There's a factory class which takes a `SchemaMutable` and gives you the `Schema`.

Downsides:

- Again, there are two classes for each type of business object.
- And again, ensuring that the states of these objects remain consistent with each other could be difficult.

Comment: Why aren't you using an out of the box ORM? This is not a wheel that you want to reinvent.

Comment: @RubberDuck This is an experimental project. I want to see what happens if I implement some ideas that haven't been implemented before.

Comment: What do you mean "you can't create a Table without specifying which Schema it belongs to"?  Table does not need to be a aware of the schema it is in.

Comment: @Paparazzi That's correct. But if a table *does* know what schema it belongs to, *then* it's impossible to create an immutable `Table` object without specifying the schema.

Comment: Then I suggest you fix the question because the current definition of a table is name and columns.

Comment: @Paparazzi That's a good point; thanks. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

There is another approach to solving this problem. You could use classes that are immutable for the API consumer. You could then include an extra class, which takes care of creating objects and linking them together. This class could have internal access to mutate the objects. Because you now have full control of what scenarios you want to support for creating and mutating the objects, you can then reason about the things you need to check and update for each of these scenarios.

Constructors for these objects would be private.

The API consumer would only need to know about the Context class, but from that point on the API is self discover-able.

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect but could go with a write once

```
private string prop = string.Empty;
public string Prop 
{
    get { return prop; }
    set 
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prop))
           prop = value;
    }
}
```

op edit the question

so for Schema constructor

```
public Schema ( List<columun> columns, string name ) 
{
     foreach (column col in columns)
     {
        if (col != null)
           throw proper exception
        col.Schema = this;
     }
     _columns = columns; 
     _name = name;
}
```